# How to make a button invisible and another button visible when the user clicks it

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am very new at Spring MVC + Thymelaf.

In my Spring MVC + Thymeleaf application I have two buttons. I want to make one of them visible when the user clicks another, and make invisible the one which was clicked by the user previously. You can see the sample code below.

```
   <input type="button" value="First Button" /> 
   <input type="button" value="Second Button           th:disabled="${model.disabled}"/>
```

Comment: Without any reload of the complete site it will not be possible. You should use Javascript.

Comment: it can't be done by using Spring MVC ?

Comment: It can: Your controller has to evaluate the request and then set a model-value for thymeleaf. BUT: that is no nice and modern solution. P.S.: `th:disabled` doesn't make your imput invisible. Use `th:if` instead.

Comment: It's correct, you should use JS if you don't want a site reload and th:if if a reload is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `th:classappend`.

**Example code :**

```
    <style>
        .hide{
            display : none;
        }
       .show{
            display : inline;
        }
    </style>
     <input type="button" value="First Button" /> 
       <input type="button" value="Second Button     
    th:classappend="${model.disabled}? 'hide' : 'show'" />
```